# How to know which one of the stored procedures filled the data in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two stored procedures inserting data into a single table. I want to retrieve data inserted by a particular stored procedure. In other sense I want to know which stored procedure stored what data in that table.

Comment: Do you think that SQL server is secretly storing that information (and thousands of other little details that people might want to know about, e.g. *when* it was inserted, *who* inserted it, *which* machine the request originated from) just on the off-chance that someone *might* want to query for it? Can you imagine how much additional storage overhead that would impose? If you want such information, then you need to put something in place where *you* record that information.

Comment: I got it. But is there a way to find what data has come from which stored proc. In my case there are only two stored procs..

Answer (score 2):

Add Extra field in table.It is easiest way. Like 'Source'
And Store Procudeure name in table column

Comment: Good idea. But I couldn't change the table now which is written a long ago. Any other ideas..

Comment: If you can not change your existing table structure, you can add new table which track , table PK and SP Name.So you can easily identify. Otherwise , i think SQL Server does not store any information about source of table data.

Comment: than probably you can add signature inside the same column like data of `123Source` or `123VBC` etc

Answer (score 0):

Add extra column to the table and keep procedure's signature there